# Calculate the implied correlation for missing cells in a correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data, matrix, copula

I have a correlation matrix in R. Many of the correlations are specified, but there are some that are "NA".

eg,
        A   __    B  __     C

A   100%    NA  25%

B   NA  100%    50%

C   25% 50% 100%

A & B are only correlated to the extent that either one is correlated with C (25% for A, and 50% for B). Is there any way (in R) to calculate the implied correlation of A & B, or to model the correlation matrix with the NA's?

Comment: You mean by adding the argument `na.rm=T`, or using pairwise correlation for matrices?

Comment: I'm not sure where you would use na.rm. I want to calculate the implied correlations where the only correlation is coming from a third, mutually correlated random variable.

Comment: This blog post I wrote a long time ago may be useful: http://jakewestfall.org/blog/index.php/2013/09/17/geometric-argument-for-constraints-on-corrxz-given-corrxy-and-corryz/

Answer (score 2):

If you have no other information, it is not possible to infer what is the value of the missing correlations. To have a valid correlation matrix the only requirement is that it is positive definite (apart from the fact that needs to be symmetric and have ones in the diagonal).

For example, in the example you gave you can set the correlation between A and B to zero, i.e.,

```r
R <- diag(3)
R[1, 3] <- R[3, 1] <- 0.25
R[2, 3] <- R[3, 2] <- 0.5

R
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 1.00  0.0 0.25
#> [2,] 0.00  1.0 0.50
#> [3,] 0.25  0.5 1.00

eigen(R)$values
#> [1] 1.559017 1.000000 0.440983
```

and you get a valid positive definite matrix (i.e., all eigen values are positive). But you also get a valid correlation matrix when you set the correlation to 0.2, e.g.,

```r
R <- diag(3)
R[1, 3] <- R[3, 1] <- 0.25
R[2, 3] <- R[3, 2] <- 0.5
R[1, 2] <- R[2, 1] <- 0.2

R
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 1.00  0.2 0.25
#> [2,] 0.20  1.0 0.50
#> [3,] 0.25  0.5 1.00

eigen(R)$values
#> [1] 1.6548674 0.8482407 0.4968919
```

But not for example if you set it to 0.99 because the last eigen value is negative, i.e.,

```r
R <- diag(3)
R[1, 3] <- R[3, 1] <- 0.25
R[2, 3] <- R[3, 2] <- 0.5
R[1, 2] <- R[2, 1] <- 0.99

R
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 1.00 0.99 0.25
#> [2,] 0.99 1.00 0.50
#> [3,] 0.25 0.50 1.00

eigen(R)$values
#> [1]  2.2227098  0.8025721 -0.0252819
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw on a different post that there was a suggestion to maximize the determinant of the new matrix. Do you know how to do that in R? The idea is that the partial correlation is zero - we only get correlation from other correlated random variables

Comment: To maximize the determinant, write the determinant as a function of the unknown correlations and use `optim`